# With XSLT, in which way can I use the apply-templates instead of the for-each loop

Tags: html, xml, templates, xslt, xsd

//I need to make it so only CDs with prices less than 25 will appear on the page. However I am restricted to using the apply-templates command and cannot use the for-each. NOTE: I cannot use the for-each as my demonstrator wants to assess our ability to use the apply templates command

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="show.xsl"?> 

<cdstore>
<cd>
<title>The bests</title>
<price>23.90 </price>
<year>2005 </year>
</cd>

<cd>
<title>The leasts</title>
<price>29.90 </price>
<year>2008 </year>
</cd>

<cd>
<title>The middles</title>
<price>15.90 </price>
<year>2011 </year>
</cd>
</cdstore>

<!--
<?xml version ="1.1" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?>
<xml: stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org">

<xsl: template match = "cdstore">
<html>
<body>
<h3> CDs sale </h3>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
</html>
<xsl:template match="cd">

<p>
<xsl:apply-templates select = "title"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select = "year"/>
</p>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "title">
Title: <span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "year">
Year: <span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span><br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

-->
```

//How can I use the xsd:apply templates command to make it so only the titles and years appear for costs less than 25? WITHOUT using the for-each loop. I'm not sure if I put the commands in the apply-templates or a part of the value-of. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: "*I am restricted to using the apply-templates command and cannot use the for-each.*" Why?     **+** Please post a **complete** XML.

Comment: Sure thing, and thank you for your swift response. 
I cant use the for-each as my demonstrator wants to assess our ability to use apply-templates as an alternative to for-each

Answer (score 1):

You can do either - you could change the `apply-templates` to restrict which elements you're applying templates *to*:

```
<h3> CDs sale </h3>
<xsl:apply-templates select="cd[price &lt; 25]"/>
```

Or alternatively you could leave it applying templates to all the `cd` elements but add a second template alongside the existing `match="cd"` one to match the elements you *don't* want, and ignore them

```
<xsl:template match="cd[price &gt;= 25]" />
```

When you have two different templates that could match the same node, the one that is chosen depends on [specific rules in the XSLT specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict), but essentially a match pattern of `"elementname[predicate]"` will always win over one matching just `"elementname"`, which in turn will win over one matching `"*"` or `"node()"`.